# How to detect cycle in edge list representation of graph?

Tags: c++, graph, minimum-spanning-tree, kruskals-algorithm

I have written a graph structure as an edge list, and am trying to write Kruskal's MST algorithm for it.

Here's my code so far:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
struct _ { ios_base::Init i; _() { cin.sync_with_stdio(0); cin.tie(0); } } _;

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    #define endl '\n'
    #define ll long long
    #define pb push_back
    #define mt make_tuple
    #define in(a) for (auto& i: a)
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

#define edge tuple < ll, ll, ll >

bool func (edge a, edge b) { return get<2>(a) < get<2>(b); }

struct graph
{
    ll v;
    vector <edge> edgelist;
    void addedge (edge x) { edgelist.pb(x); }
    ll find (vector <ll> parent, ll i) 
    { return parent[i]==-1 ? i : find (parent, parent[i]); }
    bool cycle()
    {
        vector <ll> parent (v);
        fill (parent.begin(), parent.end(), -1);
        in (edgelist)
        {
            ll x = find (parent, get<0>(i));
            ll y = find (parent, get<1>(i));
            if (x==y) return true;
            else parent[x]=y;
        }
        return false;
    }

    graph mst()
    {
        sort (edgelist.begin(), edgelist.end(), func);
        graph tree;
        in(edgelist)
        {
            graph temp = tree;
            temp.addedge(i);
            if (!temp.cycle()) tree=temp;
        }
        return tree;
    }

};


int main()
{
    graph g;
    cin >> g.v;
    ll e;
    cin >> e;
    for (ll i=1; i<=e; i++)
    {
        ll a, b, w;
        cin >> a >> b >> w;
        g.addedge(mt(a, b, w));
    }
    graph mstree = g.mst();
    in(mstree.edgelist) cout << get<0>(i) << " " << get<1>(i) << " " << get<2>(i) << endl;
    cout << endl;

}

/*
Sample Input
4 5
0 1 10
0 2 6
0 3 5
1 3 15
2 3 4

Sample Output
2 3 4
0 3 5
0 1 10
*/
```

My code takes a very long time to produce the output. Are there any problems in my implementation? Also, if I loop this task for multiple graphs, my program crashes in the middle of execution.

Comment: Have you read on [disjoin-sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure)? Or how you have read on Kruskal and missed the disjoin set part?

Comment: I could not understand how to implement union find algorithm for edge list.
I'm looking for some pseudocode to understand it in this context.

Comment: Then it will be better to show what you have tried w.r.t. union find, and explain what you do not understand. Also, you run the disjoin set on _vertices_, not on _edges_.

Comment: Also, even the Wikipedia article I linked has some pseudocode.

Comment: If I run disjoint set on vertices, then will I not have to change the whole implementation of my graph structure, as my graph only contains edge list right now.

Comment: You do not need to change the implementation. Already each your edge knows which vertices it connects (and it would be strange if it did not know), and this is all you need.

Comment: @Petr Edited question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My code takes a very long time to produce the output. Are there any
>   problems in my implementation?

There are several problems:

First,

```
ll find (vector <ll> parent, ll i) 
{ return parent[i]==-1 ? i : find (parent, parent[i]); }
```

You pass the `parent` by value, this means copying all the array. Pass by reference (and non-const, as you will need to modify it, see point 3).

Second, in `cycle()` you do not need to check *all* edges, you need to check only the edge that is under consideration in the main loop (in `mst()`). (And do not set `parent` in `cycle()`, you need to use the same array in all `mst()`.)

Third, read on "enhancements" of disjoin-set structure (even the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) has it all explained), namely union by rank and path compression. Only with those you will achieve expected performance from the disjoin-set.

> Also, if I loop this task for multiple graphs, my program crashes in
>   the middle of execution.

It is impossible to tell not knowing how to you *loop* and what are the *multiple graphs* inputs you are using. However, I strongly suspect stack overflow on even medium-sized graphs as you pass `parent` by value, thus quickly consuming the stack.